# No reaction on user field validator (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    acc_types_lst = AccountType.objects.values_list('Name', flat=True).order_by('ID')

    Name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, label='Имя')
    Surname = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, label='Фамилия')
    DateOfBirth = forms.DateField(required=True, label='Дата рождения',
                              input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d', '%m.%d.%Y', '%m.%d.%y'])
    Address = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, label='Адрес',
                          widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 55, 'rows': 5}))
    Postcode = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Почтовый индекс')
    Phone = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, label='Телефон')
    PassportID = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, label='Номер паспорта')
    AccountType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[x for x in enumerate(acc_types_lst)],
                                required=True, label='Тип счета')
    DepositeSize = forms.IntegerField(required=True, label='Начальный вклад')

    def clean_name(self):
        name = re.match('^[a-zA-Z]*$', self.cleaned_data['Name']).group()
        if name is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Имя не корректно или строка пуста!")
        else:
            return name
    ...

    def clean_deposit(self):
        deposite_size = int(self.cleaned_data['DepositeSize'])
        acc_type = AccountType.objects.values('Name', 'MinDep').get(ID=1)['MinDep']
        if deposite_size < int(acc_type):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Тип счета "+acc_type['Name']+" требует минимум "+acc_type['MinDep'] + "!")
        else:
            return deposite_size
```

But i can't understand one thing: why user validator (clean_deposit) doesn't raise exception? Yep, i'll checks this at "manage.py shell", but at real situation (debug-mode) system pass this.

Comment: Assuming that Django maps it by field name, `clean_deposit` should be `clean_depositsize` (or else the `DepositSize` field should be named `deposit`.)

Comment: Agree with Sean, try printing something in `clean_deposit` to see if it's actually being called at all.

Comment: Also some style concerns - fields are usually written as `snake_case = ` rather than `CamelCaps = `. So your `DepositeSize = ` should be `deposite_size = `.